# Correct way to save data with mvvm when navigating between pages

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm working on a universal app but I'm confused as to what is the best way to save data when using MVVM. I'm using MVVM light with this project

I have a page (i.e. LocationsPage) with a ListBox binded to an observable collection that contains objects of type LocationViewModel.

There is a 'New' button at the bottom of the LocationsPage to allow the user to create a new location.

When clicked, it navigates to another page i.e. LocationPage.

This page contains all the necessary fields to create a new location and at the bottom of the page, I have a 'Save' button.

When clicked, I want to returned back to the LocationsPage which contains the list and add the newly create location to that list and I also want to save the data to file.

Is there a way to achieve this without using code-behind (i.e. OnNavigatedTo, OnNavigatedFrom)?

I know a quick fix would be to make the observable collection global between the pages so that the newly created location object could be added to it directly but that I don't like that idea to be honest.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how best to handle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps passing the collection to the "child" view model? Or even the Parent View Model as ILocations that has an AddNew method?

Comment: I'm trying something similar where my LocationPage is now binded to my LocationsViewModel, but more specifically LocationsViewModel.SelectedLocation. The Save Location is now in the LocationsViewModel and adds the "SelectedLocation" object to the observable collection. Does that seem ok? If not, I'll give your suggestion a shot.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that and if it fits your model well then go for it.

Comment: Any idea how I can resolve this? When I click on the + button, I set my SelectedLocation = new LocationViewModel(...) but when my LocationPage gets initialized, it creates a new LocationViewModel. I think because of this, my SaveLocationCommand and CancelLocationCommand don't get triggered. I might try your suggestion tomorrow and see if it helps but I liked the way I was going about it, so if you have any suggestions as to how I could fix this, I'd appreciated your feedback. Cheers.

Comment: Why is the page creating a new VM? Should be using the SelectedLocation. Without seeing the code can't comment more, sorry.

Comment: Hi Mark, sorry I stupidly renamed my RelayCommand and didn't rename them in my xaml! Problem fixed. Thanks.